# Put iMac display to sleep using Magic Keyboard with Lock Key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I've just upgraded to the 2021 Magic Keyboard with Lock Key (A2450). I used to be able to put my iMac's display to sleep using the **Control–Shift–Media Eject** shortcut. But now I have a **Lock** key instead of an **Eject** key. So how would I be able to put my display to sleep using a keyboard shortcut? (*Without* actually locking it.)

UPDATE:

I've been able to put my display to sleep using a hot corner. I'm still looking for a keyboard shortcut, but at least I have something.

Comment: Did you tried Control-Shift-Command-E ? Never tested but as Command-E do média eject , it may run. But anyway, you can define your own key shortcut on MacOS : Apple menu/System preferences/Keyboard then Shortcuts

Comment: Good idea, but that shortcut didn't work. I don't think the 'put display to sleep' action is listed in the Keyboard preferences.

Comment: Did you try a long press? Works on the new M1 iMacs

Comment: Long press on which key/shortcut?

Comment: The fingerprint key

Comment: I don't have the fingerprint key since I have the cheaper keyboard with a lock key instead. (I have an Intel Mac.)

Comment: Well you can press option+shift+power button. This will put your displays to sleep

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), it's a awesome, free and open source software.

- In the Preferences of Karabiner-Elements, select "Complex Modifications", click "Add rule" at the bottom, click "Import more rules from the internet (Open a web browser)".
- In the [opened web page](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/), search for "Sleep Monitor" you will find ["Add Sleep Monitor for Keyboard without Eject"](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#sleep-monitor), click "Import" on the right, and "Open Karabiner-Elements.app".
- When back to Karabiner-Elements, click "Import", and "Enable" the rule.

Then you can try the keys <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>esc</kbd>.

There are also a lot of magic rule [here](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/).